# moderncv - newline within a cventry in the banking style

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

I want to find a way to split long line in the 3rd element of `\cventry`. I use **moderncv** package and **banking** style. Using \newline doesn't help. I get the result in the picture using following code. I want to have the word "markets" go to the 2nd line, and "Euro-Finance company" to the 3rd line.

```
\cventry{2006}{Euro-Finance company}{Certified as technical and fundamental analyst of international financial \newline markets}{MyCity, MyCountry}{}{}
```

Below is the definition of `\cventry` in the moderncvstylebanking.sty. I tried to modify it but wasn't able to reach my goal, as I don't understand most of that code.

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
  {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
  {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
\else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
```

[image: Bad result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\cventry` as

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{7cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
  {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
  {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
\else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
\par\addvspace{#1}}
```

and adjust `7cm` to your needs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{banking}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{7cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
  {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
  {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
\else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
\par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2006}{Euro-Finance company}{Certified as technical and fundamental analyst of international financial markets}{MyCity, MyCountry}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found how can I accomplish what I wanted, by modifying my entry in a following way

```
\cventry{2006}{\textnormal{\textbf{markets}}}{Certified as technical and fundamental analyst of international financial}{City, Country}{}{\normalsize{\textit{Euro-Finance company}}}
```

[image: Good output]

But, I think, this is very artificial and not convenient for general use.